# JSTL I changed language and on other sub pages is back to default language

Tags: java, jsp, internationalization, jstl

I have problem with JSTL formatting library. When I changed and clicked link to other subpage it return me site with default language, not with this what I chose.

**I have four files with messages:**

mylabels_pl_PL.properties

mylabels_en_EN.properties

mylabels_de_DE.properties

mylabels.properties

**Entry point of web application is file: index.jsp**

content:

```
  <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
  <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>

 <c:set var="theLocale" value="${not empty param.theLocale ? param.theLocale : pageContext.request.locale}" scope="session" />
 <fmt:setLocale value="${theLocale}" />
 <fmt:setBundle basename="multilanguage.mylabels" />

 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>
        <fmt:message key="label.title" />
    </title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/index.js" async></script>
</head>


<body onload="assignDestinationForm()">

    <header class="languages">
        <nav>
            <ul>        
                <li>
                    <a href="index.jsp?theLocale=en_EN">
                        <img src="img/england.jpg" alt="" id="imgEngland">
                    </a>
                </li>       
                <li>
                    <a href="index.jsp?theLocale=de_DE">
                        <img src="img/germany.jpg" alt="" id="imgGermany">
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="index.jsp?theLocale=pl_PL">
                        <img src="img/poland.jpg" alt="" id="imgPoland">
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div style="clear: both;"></div>

    <header class="title">
        <h1>
            <fmt:message key="label.title" />
        </h1>
    </header>

    <article>
        <section>

        </section>
    </article>

    <div id="container">
        <form id="myForm" action="">
            <button id="btnSignIn">
                <fmt:message key="label.login" />
            </button>
            <button id="btnSignUp">
                <fmt:message key="label.register" />
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <fmt:message key="label.footer" />
    </footer>

</body>
```

**second subpage: login-form.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>

<c:set var="theLocale" value="${not empty param.theLocale ? param.theLocale : pageContext.request.locale}" scope="session" />
<fmt:setLocale value="${theLocale}" />
<fmt:setBundle basename="multilanguage.mylabels" />

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>
        <fmt:message key="label.login" />
    </title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login-form.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/index.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="assignDestinationForm()">

    <header class="languages">
        <nav>
            <ul>        
                <li>
                    <a href="login-form.jsp?theLocale=en_EN">
                        <img src="img/england.jpg" id="btnEngland" alt="">
                    </a>
                </li>       
                <li>
                    <a href="login-form.jsp?theLocale=de_DE">
                        <img src="img/germany.jpg" id="btnGermany" alt="">
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="login-form.jsp?theLocale=pl_PL">
                        <img src="img/poland.jpg" id="btnPoland" alt="">
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <article>
        <section>
            <h1>
                <fmt:message key="label.login" />
            </h1>
            <div id="container">
                <form action="" method="get">
                    <fmt:message key="label.username" /> <br />
                    <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName">
                    <br /><br />
                    <fmt:message key="label.password" /> <br />
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password"> 
                    <br /><br />
                    <button id="btnForm">
                        <fmt:message key="label.btnLogin" />
                    </button>           
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>
    </article>





    <footer>
        <fmt:message key="label.footer" />
    </footer>   

</body>
```

I have page register-form.jsp yet but there is only form for sign up and look like similar to login-form.jsp.

How set that after clicked on image with flag of the country assign specified language and after click on the link to login-form.jsp the will be the same chose language?

Comment: Well, both pages set the **page** locale from the request parameter "theLocale" (which, I guess, is absent) or from the **request** locale. Why do you think that the second one should reuse the locale set in the first one?

Comment: So, I should use something like it ? <fmt:setBundle basename=""multilanguage.mylabels".${theLocale}" /> On the first page I set language and variable theLocale store value (en_US) and this value should be assign to attribute of setBundle tag?

Comment: No. The base name of the bundle is always the same, and doesn't depend on the locale. If you want the first page to set a locale, and the second one to use the one set in the first page, then don't set the locale in the second page, and set it to the session scope in the first, not to the default page scope.